# how to extract key value from bash string

Tags: bash

I am trying to extract the value of a, b and c from the given bash string:

```
x='a: 7  b: 2  c: 7'
```

But I am not able to find a simpler way yet, tried to convert the string to array, but that works on the assumption that a, b and c are in sequence.

Comment: What have you tried? "not able to find a simpler way" … simpler than what exactly?

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description, no images, no links) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Sorry for not adding what i tried , i tried below: array_x=($x)
a="${array_x[1]}"
b="${array_x[3]}"
c="${array_x[5]}"

Comment: I need to extract keys as 3 more bash variable and assign the given value to them so it becomes a=7; b=2 and c=7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use parameter expansion.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

x='a: 7  b: 2  c: 7'
x=" $x"
for key in a b c ; do
    value=${x#* $key: }  # Remove everything before " k: " where k is the key
    value=${value%% *}   # Remove everything after the first space
    echo Value of "$key" is "$value"
done
```

Comment: this breaks if i change the sequence of a, b and c. x='a: 7  c: 2  b: 7' , I dont know what sequence it would be. but yes those keys will exists in the string

Comment: @KamalSinghal: What do you mean by "breaks"? I'm still getting the correct values. Do you mean you want to get the keys in the same order, too?

Comment: No,  my bad... i again rechecked it and getting the right value, so This works as expected. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Does the key always come before a colon and comprises only non-blank characters? If so, what prevents you from running `grep` with the `--only-matching` option? Clean up the output with `cut` (or `tr -d` or `sed`)

```
echo "$x" | grep -o '[^ ]*:' | cut -d: -f1
```

Or, if you want the values (not the keys) – which is not clear from the question – you could split on the double-space (assuming the format is always exactly like that).

```
echo "$x" | sed 's/  /\n/g' | cut -d: -f2- | cut -c2-
```

Comment: I need to extract keys as 3 more bash variable and assign the given value to them